# MVC4 Data Annotations Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

This is my first time trying to use Data Annotations, and I keep receiving the above error when trying to test the validation.

My model looks like:

```
    public class SupplierValidationModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Company Name:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is Required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Address:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Address is Required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company City:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company City is Required")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company State:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company State is Required")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Zip:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Zip is Required")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Phone:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Phone is Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "A Valid Phone Number is Required")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Name:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact Name is Required")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact E-Mail:")]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Valid E-Mail Required")]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Phone:")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}", ErrorMessage = "A Valid Phone Number is Required")]
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Added By:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Added By Must Be Entered")]
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
}
```

With my view looking like this;

```
@model SupplierValidationModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertSupplier", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.City)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City)</td>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.State)</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, StateList.States) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.State)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Zip)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Zip)</td>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactName)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactName)</td>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactEmail)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactEmail) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactEmail)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContactPhone)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactPhone) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContactPhone)</td>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddedBy)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddedBy) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AddedBy)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Add Supplier" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="@ViewBag.Employee.AccountName" />
    }
```

And finally my Action is;

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertSupplier(SupplierValidationModel model)
    {
       // string userName = coll["userId"].ToString();            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DataOps.InsertSupplier(model);
            return View();

        }else{
            ViewData["Valid"] = false;
            //return RedirectToAction("SupplierInfo", "Admin", new {employeeAcct = userName });
            return View(model);

        }
    }
```

No matter what when I return the View() again and just want to load the form back up with the associated error messages i get the cannot perform runtime error.

I have gone through numerous tutorials, and everything is loading correctly in the ModelState, with it not being valid, but never renders the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably @ViewBag.Employee that you have in your hidden field is null. If you loaded that in the GET action you have to load on the POST too.

Comment: you're right! that's my mistake completely, not passing back the ViewBag values in the reload. thank you